# What are the Numbers shown in SVN repository Eclipse Plugin

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

A very basic question. What does the numbers shown in each node of the SVN Eclipse Plugin shows? I started using SVN recently only. Am seeing a number corresponding to each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the revision numbers of the last commit that affected that node.
See also this explanation of the concept of the "Mixed revisions working copy": http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are the revision numbers for each node.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and talking about numbers such as those visible here:
[image: Eclipse screenshot]
<sub>(source: [tigris.org](http://subclipse.tigris.org/images/workspace-ss.png))</sub>

Then those are the revision numbers of each node shown.